# scroling replaces table view cell values while searching

Tags: iphone, ios

i was implementing the searching criteria having customized cells. Everything is going fine but while searching in table view it shows correct cell at very first row but when i scroll then it shows strange behaviour.. the cell which are deallocating and reallocating replaces the values in rows which already in other rows. What should i do to fix the cell values where they were at same index.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

contentForname = nil;
contentFordesc = nil;
contentForindicator = nil;
contentForprice = nil;
contentForchef = nil;
contentForspecial = nil;
contentForspicy = nil;
contentForimage = nil;

if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView])
{
    [self.tableview setHidden:YES];
    tableView.frame=CGRectMake(15, 92, 295, 361);
    tableView.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];


    contentForname      =[[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:0+j*8];
    contentFordesc      =[[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:1+j*8];
    contentForindicator =[[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:2+j*8];
    contentForprice     =[[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:3+j*8];
    contentForchef      =[[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:4+j*8];
    contentForspecial   =[[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:5+j*8];
    contentForspicy     =[[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:6+j*8];
    contentForimage     =[[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:7+j*8];

    j++;

}
else
{
 contentForname      = [[[self contentsList] objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"name"];
 contentFordesc      = [[[self contentsList] objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"description"];
 contentForindicator = [[[self contentsList] objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"indicator"];
 contentForprice     = [[[self contentsList] objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"price"];    
 contentForchef      =  [[[self contentsList] objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"chef"];  
 contentForspecial   = [[[self contentsList] objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"special"]; 
 contentForspicy     =  [[[self contentsList] objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"spicy"];   
  contentForimage    =  [[[self contentsList] objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"itemimage"];  

  }
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120,20, 230, 20)];
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16];
    nameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    nameLabel.tag = 100;
    [cell addSubview:nameLabel];

    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edittext.png"]];
    [tempImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 297, 130)];
    [cell addSubview:tempImageView];
    [cell sendSubviewToBack:tempImageView];

    cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"veg.png"]];
    [cellImage setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 50, 50)];
    [cell addSubview:cellImage];

    descTextview = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120,50, 200, 100)];
    descTextview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    descTextview.tag=102;
    descTextview.editable=FALSE;
    descTextview.scrollEnabled=TRUE;
    [cell addSubview:descTextview];

    priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 15, 60, 25)];
    priceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    priceLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16];
    priceLabel.tag=101;
    [cell addSubview:priceLabel];
}
nameLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
nameLabel.text = contentForname;
priceLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rs: %@",contentForprice];
descTextview = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:102];
descTextview.text = contentFordesc;
return cell;
}
```

actually, when every times cell is created at `cellforrowatindex` `j` is incremented so that i can give proper values to indexes from `searchresult` array by logic like `0+j*8`, but as soon as i scroll while searching, values in cell get changed. In short i am not able to fix the indexes values from search result. It seems that cell values shuffles.

Comment: Looks like [cell viewWithTag:100]; for some reason returns nil for the reused cells, could you check it ? You can turn breakpoint on right before start to scroll the tableview.

Comment: What is the variable `j`?  I don't see anywhere in your code where you  declare it.  I'm also perplexed by the indexing scheme in your `searchResults`; why is it different than that of the `contentList`?  Also, where do you declare `contentForname` and all of the other content variables?  Are they local scope?  (They should be.)

Comment: @alanduncan : j is simply NSInteger. contentForname and all other is NSMutablString in .h class.I cant understand the question 'why is it different than that of the contentList?'

Comment: This is due to cellreuse, either you need to make it nil or need to remove identifier for newly created cell and then use reuse identifier again for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use different reuse identifier for cells in search results table and in the main table, so that they don't interfere with each other.